# How to Make Multi Record File Appear as One Record

Tags: sql, db2

In my web application I have an input field that can hold a large string. Before the record is saved it is broken down into 80 character length records. In an ireport I need to display the strings of each record as one string.

Comment: While I hate people asking *why* you want to do something - I cant help myself here. Why are you manipulating your data to break apart something that *is* into something it *isnt*? Surely if you need to somewhere down the track treat it as 80 character records you can do it on output or formatting?

Comment: @TomC - `iReport` and 80 characters makes me assume this is the AS/400 or System i version, which historically was interacted with through a 5250 (emulated) terminal - and is limited to 80 or 132 characters wide.  So they'd just splat the file out to the display (or printer), which would also have the benefit of putting the records in storage order....

Comment: @Steve - please, what platform and version are you using, because that makes a huge difference in the capabilities available for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think on two methods: One static and one recursive:

Lets suppose your messages table has three columns, message_id, sequence, message_line, where message_id uniquely identifies the hole message, and sequence enumerate the message lines.

If you are interested in the n first lines, you can use a static query such as

```
SELECT 
    A.MESSAGE_ID, A.MESSAGE_LINE || ' ' || 
    COALESCE(B.MESSAGE_LINE, '') || ' ' || 
    COALESCE(C.MESSAGE_LINE, '') || ' ' || 
    COALESCE(D.MESSAGE_LINE, '')
FROM
    MESSAGES A
LEFT JOIN MESSAGES B ON A.MESSAGE_ID = B.MESSAGE_ID AND A.SEQUENCE+1 = B.SEQUENCE
LEFT JOIN MESSAGES C ON B.MESSAGE_ID = C.MESSAGE_ID AND B.SEQUENCE+1 = C.SEQUENCE
LEFT JOIN MESSAGES D ON C.MESSAGE_ID = D.MESSAGE_ID AND C.SEQUENCE+1 = D.SEQUENCE
WHERE A.SEQUENCE = 1;
```

If you want all lines, you can use a more complex recursive query such as:

```
WITH AA (MESSAGE_ID, SEQUENCE, MESSAGE_LINE) AS (
SELECT
    MESSAGE_ID,
    SEQUENCE,
    CAST(MESSAGE_LINE AS VARCHAR(1000))
FROM
    MESSAGES
WHERE 
    SEQUENCE = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    B.MESSAGE_ID,
    B.SEQUENCE,
    CAST((AA.MESSAGE_LINE || ' ' || B.MESSAGE_LINE) AS VARCHAR(1000))
FROM
    MESSAGES B, 
    AA
WHERE
    B.MESSAGE_ID = AA.MESSAGE_ID
AND B.SEQUENCE = AA.SEQUENCE  + 1
)
SELECT AA.MESSAGE_ID, AA.MESSAGE_LINE 
FROM AA, (SELECT MESSAGE_ID, MAX(SEQUENCE) AS SEQUENCE 
          FROM MESSAGES 
          GROUP BY MESSAGE_ID) BB
WHERE AA.MESSAGE_ID = BB.MESSAGE_ID
AND AA.SEQUENCE = BB.SEQUENCE;
```

Tips:

(1) the first query before the UNION ALL is the non-recursive part, the spark that ignites the query. The portion after UNION ALL is the recursive one.

(2) CAST(...) is to convert the CHAR(80) to a greater column large enough to allocate the hole message.

Be carefull with performance. Tuning recursive queries may be difficult and in some cases, it will be easier to develop a regular Stored Procedure or a User Defined Table Function (UDTF).

Comment: Please, don't use the comma-separated `FROM` clause, it's much easier to comprehend a query when the relevant conditions are placed next to the table: explicitly qualify your joins.

Comment: Thanks @Clockwork-Muse for your comment.  The fullselect of the recursive common table expression must be the UNION of two or more fullselects and cannot include an explicit join including an ON clause.  Now, my query is only a curiosity, given that since Db2 10.1, LISTAGG is supported in Db2 and it does the work easier, cleaner, faster, and is more reliable that recursive queries.

Comment: Well, I meant the outer query level, really.  (I keep forgetting DB2 has this restriction - for some reason I thought this worked on the iSeries version, but I can't check it now...)

Answer (score 1):

Read about the [LISTAGG aggregate function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html).

```
with t (str) as (values 
  '1-st string'
, '2-nd string'
, '3-rd string'
)
select listagg(str) final_string
from t;
```

The result is:

```
FINAL_STRING
---------------------------------
1-st string2-nd string3-rd string
```

You can use some custom separator in the 2-nd function parameter if needed.